# Can a power board impact watt meter readings

Tags: mains, board, power-meter

I've just measured two different but conflicting readings using an off the shelf watt meter. My quandary is that these measurements conflict and seem untrustworthy.

**My question is:** whether measuring from a power board or the wall plug matters or if there is something else at play here that I've missed?

**Setup:**

- Reader: Arlec Electrical Meter (PC222)
- Power Board: HPM 12 Socket with surge protection and indicator light
- Device 1 & 2 & 3 Connected to power board. Power board connected to wall plug.

**Notes:** Device 2 runs under seemingly constant load/utilization for both readings.

**Method:**

*1st Reading:*
820W measured at power board plug from Device 2. ~247V. PF of 97%

*2nd Reading:*
220W measured at wall plug of power board with Devices 1&3 on and consuming.

*3nd Reading:*
630W measured at wall plug of power board with all devices consuming. ~247V. PF of 87%

Edit: These devices are electronic and 2 have computer PSU's.

Comment: PF has a value no greater than 1.

Comment: You have provided no links to the datasheets for these devices. We don't know whether you are exceeding the ratings, or trying to measure a few hundred watts with a device intended for hundreds of kilowatts.